# Offline flutter sdk upgrade

Tags: flutter

I'm going to update Flutter SDK and recently I've downloaded latest Flutter SDK with .zip extension. Is it possible to make offline update of Flutter SDK?

Thanks))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to just replace old sdk with new one(after unzipping it) and run "flutter doctor" command. If you want to place your sdk in another folder with another path, you'll need to update your path, see [Junsu Cho's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63462489/10084055) answer.

Answer (score 1):

unzip to flutter zip file,

update your flutter path

link url : https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

Comment: Actually you don't need to update your path to flutter/dart. Only what you need is to replace flutter(copy/paste) and after that run "flutter doctor". My question wasn't correct, I need to update it. But thanks for your response!)) So, new problem occures: while you make this process all implemented libraries are erasing(( Need to see where flutter downloading  libraries.